# How to view exception details in Visual Studio Express?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, exception, visual-studio-2012, stack-trace

How do you view exception details such as messages and stack traces in VS Express 2012? I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone, and whenever an exception is thrown while debugging, all Visual Studio does is highlight the line of code at which the exception occurred. [image: Screenshot of the problem]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Exception Assistant has been removed from the Express versions of Visual Studio 2012.  From [here:](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/762652/enable-exception-assistant-option-missing-from-vs2012-express-for-desktop)

> You are correct that we intentionally removed the exception assistant from the WDX sku for VS 2012. In 2012, pro and above are required for this functionality. You should be able to view the exception information in the watch window including the inner exception.
>
> We'll take your feedback and look into possibly adding this dialog back into the express skus in a future release but we have no plans of changing this for 2012 at this time.
>
> Marc Paine
>
> Visual Studio Debugger QA Lead

Unless there's an update one day to add it back, you'd have to buy a full version of VS 2012.

Answer (score 26):

You can press `Break` button and then look into exception details under `Locals`. Look for `$exception` there.

Comment: Break is greyed out for me if an exception has been thrown. The only options are to continue or to stop. There's no $exception in the Locals window. You can get around this by putting $exception in the watch window though

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what a bother! But luckily, unless the exception is thrown in external code, you can defuse the situation by temporarily enveloping the offending code line in a try catch block, then setting a break point inside catch:

[image]