# How to use VSExpress 2012 Watch window

Tags: exception, visual-studio-2012

I started a new project in Visual Studio Express 2012 Desktop. On meeting an exception I found this answer: [How to view exception details in Visual Studio Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542831/how-to-view-exception-details-in-visual-studio-express)

The answer says that exception information should be possible to view in a Watch Window. I am not familiar with this and how to use it, and I have been unable figure out how to get the exception information from there.

So in short my request is:

Please provide detailed instructions for how to use the Watch Window to show exception details.

**Edit**
To conclude from below - the watch window isn't really that useful. You need to have the exception declared - e.g. by wrapping the offending code in a try-catch. However when you do this and break inside the catch, you can get at the information simply clicking the exception, and expanding the pop-up.

Comment: `Exception.ToString()` is *always* the best way to get what you need from an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the exception variable to Watches by right-clicking it and then clicking "Add Watch".

You can also type the name of the variable in the Watches window.

Comment: So am I correct to conclude, that that requires me to explicitly catch the exception in a try-catch?

If so, I still don't really see the usefulness of the watch window. If I wrap in a `try{//something}` `catch(Exception ex){}` i can just add a breakpoint in the catch, which gives me the error info when clicking the ex variable.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You are using Express edition which is limited in that regard.